# Adding intermittent logo to my App using Powerapps

Tags: android, ios, powerapps, graphical-logo

I am trying to create a mobile app using Powerapps, to do this I wanted to have a screen where in the background I have my company logo intermittent (blinking). Is it possible? If so how should I do it?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to achieve this is using a timer control.
You can hide the timer off screen or simply set it's Visible property to false.
You will also need to ensure the timer's **'AutoStart'** property is set to **'true'**, and the **'Repeat'** property must also be set to **'true'**.

Set the Image's transparency field to your timers value divided by it's duration property (which you will also need to set). For example, my timer is called "Fade". So I make Image1's **'Transparency'** property:

```
Fade.Value/Fade.Duration
```

This will result in the Image fading out and popping back in very suddenly.

For more info, check out the [Timer Control reference page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/controls/control-timer)